# How do I compare strings (insensitive case), while inserting same strings into a binary Tree (sensitive case)?

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, string-comparison

Essentially, I am a brick wall as to how I should compare strings with my `insert` function, not taking case into consideration while simultaneously inserting those same strings with their original case.

Here is my `insert` function.

```
TreeNode* Tree::insert(TreeNode* node, string value) {
    transform(value.begin(), value.end(), value.begin(), ::tolower);

    if (node == nullptr) {
        return newTreeNode(value);
    }
    if (node->data < value) {
        node->left = insert(node->left, value);
    }
    else if(node-> data > value) {
        node->right = insert(node->right, value);
    }
    else {
        return node;
    }
    node->height = 1 + max(height(node->left), height(node->right));
    return node;
}
```

Here is my tree header file:

```
struct TreeNode {
public:
    TreeNode* left;
    TreeNode* right;
    string data;
};

class Tree {
public:
    TreeNode * newTreeNode(string data);
    TreeNode * insert(TreeNode* node, string value);
    void lexographicPrint(TreeNode* root);
};
```

newTreeNode Funciton:

```
TreeNode* AvlTree::newTreeNode(string value) {
    TreeNode* treeNode = new TreeNode();
    treeNode->data = value;
    treeNode->left = nullptr;
    treeNode->right= nullptr;
    treeNode->height = 1;
    return treeNode;
}
```

Print Function:

```
void AvlTree::lexographicPrint(TreeNode* root) {
    if (root != nullptr) {
        lexographicPrint(root->right);
        cout << root->data << " ";
        lexographicPrint(root->left);
    }
}
```

This currently works as I want it to except for the fact that the Tree contains all values as lower case, obviously due to the `transform` function. I have tried using a `holdValue`, like so:

```
string holdValue;
if (isupper(value[0]) {
    holdValue = value;
}
```

at the top of my function, replacing all `insert` calls with `holdValue`. I am confused as to why that changes the order of my tree when comparisons are still made with `value`. I expected that to work, but it does not. I have yet to find a solution through Google searches.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with the code that does not work.

Comment: added newTreeNode() and lexicographicPrint() functions. That is what I got from the link you provided, sorry if I made it worse.

Comment: First, make a `compare` function that returns `true` or `false`, depending on whether the string being inserted is less than the string in the tree -- don't hard-code the comparison in the `insert`.  Once you have that, you have a skeleton of how you should solve the problem, and that is the `compare` function should be generic in some way.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you. Essentially, I am creating a separate `compare` where `true` can mean to insert to the left node and to the right node (or vice versa), and the compare function will ignore case while the `insert` function will hold the original values?

Comment: @Suede -- Yes -- both answers given so far by others captures the essence of what you should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use `std::string`'s `<`, you can use a case insensitive comparison.

```
bool ci_less(const std::string & lhs, const std::string & rhs) {
    return std::lexicographical_compare(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), [](char l, char r){ return std::to_lower(l) < std::tolower(r); });
}

TreeNode* Tree::insert(TreeNode* node, std::string value) {

    if (node == nullptr) {
        return newTreeNode(std::move(value));
    }
    if (ci_less(node->data, value)) {
        node->left = insert(node->left, std::move(value));
    }
    else if(ci_less(value, node->data)) {
        node->right = insert(node->right, std::move(value));
    }
    else {
        return node;
    }
    node->height = 1 + max(height(node->left), height(node->right));
    return node;
}
```

You will need to `#include <algorithm>` for `std::lexicographical_compare`.

In a similar vein, you could instead define a [case insensitive string type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits)

```
struct ci_char_traits : public std::char_traits<char> {
    static char to_upper(char ch) {
        return std::toupper((unsigned char) ch);
    }
    static bool eq(char c1, char c2) {
         return to_upper(c1) == to_upper(c2);
     }
    static bool lt(char c1, char c2) {
         return to_upper(c1) <  to_upper(c2);
    }
    static int compare(const char* s1, const char* s2, size_t n) {
        while ( n-- != 0 ) {
            if ( to_upper(*s1) < to_upper(*s2) ) return -1;
            if ( to_upper(*s1) > to_upper(*s2) ) return 1;
            ++s1; ++s2;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    static const char* find(const char* s, int n, char a) {
        auto const ua (to_upper(a));
        while ( n-- != 0 ) 
        {
            if (to_upper(*s) == ua)
                return s;
            s++;
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
};

using ci_string = std::basic_string<char, ci_char_traits>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you want to store mixed-case values, but ordered as if they were lowercase.

There are two things you can do.

1. Replace all of your `a < b` and `a > b` checks with `case_insensitive_compare(a, b) < 0` and `case_insensitive_compare(a, b) > 0`, where `case_insensitive_compare` looks something like:

   ```cpp
   // +ve => l > r
   // 0 => l equivalent to r (possibly different case)
   // -ve => l < r
   int case_insensitive_compare(const std::string& l, const std::string& r) noexcept {
       std::size_t max_size = std::max(l.size(), r.size());
       for (std::size_t i = 0; i < max_size; ++i) {
           int cmp = std::tolower(l[i]) - std::tolower(r[i]);
           if (cmp != 0) return cmp;
       }
       return l.size() - r.size();
   }

   // Or in c++20
   // std::weak_ordering::greater => l > r
   // std::weak_ordering::equivalent => l equivalent to r
   // std::weak_ordering::less => l < r
   std::weak_ordering case_insensitive_compare(const std::string& l, const std::string& r) noexcept {
       std::size_t max_size = std::max(l.size(), r.size());
       for (std::size_t i = 0; i < max_size; ++i) {
           auto cmp = std::tolower(l[i]) <=> std::tolower(r[i]);
           if (cmp != 0) return cmp;
       }
       return l.size() <=> r.size();
   }
   ```

   You should be able to generalise this to any comparator function (For a `Tree<T>`, a comparator `cmp(const T&, const T&) -> int`)
2. Make your `TreeNode` store a key/value pair, where the key is the lowercase string, and the value is the mixed-case string. If you need to make the tree store another value, make the value a `std::tuple<std::string, ValueType>`.

Comment: So essentially, a general compare function that ignores case and then still inserts the original case?